# Login to web portal using Python

Tags: python-2.7

So I have followed many guides on how to login to a portal using python using urllib2 and to parse it using 'BeautifulSoup'.

I am trying to login to this [webportal](http://academia.srmuniv.ac.in) which has its login form way nested [there](http://%20https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/accounts/signin?_sh=false&hideidp=true&portal=10002227248&client_portal=true&servicename=ZohoCreator&serviceurl=https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/)

I looked at the from tag in the source and found this

```
<form id="signinForm" action="/accounts/signin.ac" name="signinform" method="post" novalidate="true" autocomplete="off">
```

but the link 
`https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/accounts/signin.ac` is invalid.

Can someone help me with this.

**EDIT**

Code used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import urllib2 import requests 
payload = {'username': 'some_username', 'password': 'some_password'} 
r = requests.get("academia.srmuniv.ac.in/accounts/signin.ac";, params=payload) 
data = r.text soup = BeautifulSoup(data) print soup.prettify()
```

Comment: because you need to access this by a post method, so you can't just go to this link like that. what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: You probably need to do what this function: `submitSigninForm()` is doing and POST that data  (using `httplib`, perhaps) .

Pretty much just reading through the [sources of the page](https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/accounts/signin?_sh=false&hideidp=true&portal=10002227248&client_portal=true&servicename=ZohoCreator&serviceurl=https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/)

Comment: It returns the invalid page even when i make a post request @Whitefret and i want to scrape the data after logging into the portal

Comment: yeah because most of the time, you need to pass more than just logging/password, like a tokken or other hidden field

Comment: can you post your code (minus the password) so we can give you some hindsight?

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests
payload = {'username': 'some_username', 'password': 'some_password'}
r = requests.get("https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/accounts/signin.ac", params=payload)
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.prettify()

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, you need to understand the difference between a `GET` and a `POST` request.

Get is a basic http request where parameters are passed by the url. It is very limited in size and security. Post is a when the parameters are in the body of the request.

In your case, you need a POST request, so you need to use `requests.post("academia.srmuniv.ac.in/accounts/signin.ac";, params=payload)`

Also, you need to use a session so that the login persists.

Here is a small code to do that:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post('your address', payload)
```

Lastly, about the parameters, you need to pass an Email and a Password (look at the id in the input tags), and the address is relativ to an ifram, but I am not sure about what is the correct address to give...

So it should gives you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
payload = {'Email' : youremail, 'Password' : yourpwd}
r = s.post('https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/accounts/signin.ac', payload)
data = r.text()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.pretify()
```

And now to access any page in the web site, you just need to use your session and get or post:

```
r2 = s.get('some other page behind the login page')
r3 = s.post('some other page with a post method', payload)
```

Comment: it didnt work, it returned nothing

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
payload = {'email' : 'something', 'password' : 'something'}
r = s.post('https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/accounts/signin.ac', payload)
data = s.get('https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/#View:My_Attendance')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
print soup.prettify()

Comment: @RohanLokeshSharma can you try to print r.text?

Comment: it prints nothing (blank)

Comment: @RohanLokeshSharma what do you get when you do `print r.status_code`

Comment: @RohanLokeshSharma and s.status_code? sorry to ask meaningful question but I need to be sure

Comment: sorry i am a beginner, i did not understand what did you mean by data, but i get this when i print s <requests.sessions.Session object at 0x10dbc6550>

Comment: and with https//your_address?

Comment: nvm, I know the problem

Comment: login failed so your are automatically redirected without the right http code, it is the server fault...

Comment: so, that means i cant login?

Comment: no, it means that we are doing things wrong. try this addess for logging: ` https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/portal-perma/academia-academic-services/login/`

Comment: in fact, this web site got an architecture I don't really know about... So I don't really get how this works :/. I can't login so I can't check what's on the network, but you can. try to see the developper tool in your browser. I know you are not familiar with it but it will teach you a lot of useful things